# asp.net syntax for inline checkbox edit and insert vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkbox

I could use some help with the syntax for datalist control which I have added two checkboxes to 2 of the fields. Each field can be set in both Insert or Edit modes.

How can I get the Insert and Update wizard to read these values without custom coding the processes in the code behind?

Here is the ASP..

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
     AutoGenerateRows="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="keyID" 
     DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Font-Names="Verdana" ForeColor="#333333" 
     GridLines="Horizontal" Height="50px" Width="340px">
     <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" Position="TopAndBottom" 
      PageButtonCount="5" />
     <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
     <CommandRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" />
     <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
     <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#DEE8F5" Font-Bold="True" Width="160px" />
     <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
     <Fields>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="keyID" HeaderText="keyID" InsertVisible="False" 
               ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="keyID" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="typeOfDriver" HeaderText="Type Of Driver:" 
               SortExpression="typeOfDriver" />
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active Type:" SortExpression="activeType">
               <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="Checkbox1" runat="server"  Text='<%# Eval("activeType") %>'></asp:CheckBox>
               </EditItemTemplate>
               <InsertItemTemplate>
                   <asp:CheckBox ID="Checkbox2" runat="server"  Text='<%# Eval("activeType") %>' Checked="True"></asp:CheckBox>&nbsp;True
               </InsertItemTemplate>
               <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("activeType") %>'></asp:Label>
               </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Visible in GUI:" SortExpression="visible">
               <EditItemTemplate>
                   <asp:CheckBox ID="Checkbox3" runat="server"  Text='<%# Bind("visible") %>'></asp:CheckBox>
               </EditItemTemplate>
               <InsertItemTemplate>
                   <asp:CheckBox ID="Checkbox4" runat="server"  Text='<%# Bind("visible") %>' Checked="True"></asp:CheckBox>&nbsp;True      
               </InsertItemTemplate>
               <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("visible") %>'></asp:Label>
           </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowInsertButton="True" />
    </Fields>
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#99CCFF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#FFFF99" Width="260px" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
</asp:DetailsView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen this? [Working with the DataList Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23559/Working-with-the-DataList-Control).

This is also a good example: [How to edit/delete records using Datalist](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/43058-How-Edit-Delete-records-using-Data-List.aspx).

Comment: Both great examples, I will read them over but they both include code behind pages. I am trying to solve this with just inline ASP. If I can't figure this out I may need to use one of these methods.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with the ASP? Just get the values from the checkboxes?

Comment: No got that, wanted to display check box on Edit and Insert mode. The control is not picking up the values on Update or Insert.